# How to turn all network interfaces down?

Tags: networking, bash, interface

`ifconfig -a` lists all network interfaces. I need to run `sudo ifconfig <iface name> down` for each interface listed by the command. What is the ideal way to implement this inside a shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the name of each network interface listed by `ifconfig -a` in the directory /sys/class/net, which is populated by the kernel itself. Since the name of each directory in `/sys/class/net` is the actual name of the interface, you can loop over the files.

For Example:

```
for intf in /sys/class/net/*; do
    sudo ifconfig `basename $intf` down
done
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way to do this on Ubuntu 17.10, one that doesn't require installing net-tools first?